# How to solve $\int(e^{y^2 - x^2}\cos(2 x y))\,dx$?

Tags: integration

I am not sure how to solve this. Is there a way of solving this without resorting to erf? $$\int e^{y^2 - x^2} \cos(2 x y)\ dx$$

Comment: No. Erf is a non-elementary function. There is no way to write Erf in terms of simpler (i.e. elementary) functions.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question is very simple: No, [erf function cannot be expressed using elementary functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function).

If you are, instead, interested in how Mathematica can solve it and express using **erf** (while it is not trivial from the definition of **erf**), then it is totally different question and, probably, too broad for this topic.